# multi layer web project with GIT

Tags: git, multi-layer

I have many web base project that have two layer.
front layer and backend layer.
both layer files are mixed together. for rendering i cant separate them.
front files for all projects are for each project but need git.
the base layout for all project always must be sync together.

```
app/
    cntrl/
        basefile.php [base]
    view/
        baseview.phtml [base]
        thisprojectfile.phtml [front]
```

[image]

- If i ignore some layer git not work for trace modifying with
  developers in current layer.
- If i use branch for each layer another    files not be visible to use
  them.

So what's the solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You have three choices:

1. Keep all your code in one repository. You have not defined any reason why you can't do so.
2. Use [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) to link separate repositories.
3. Use [subtree merging](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-7.html) to synchronize separate repositories.

Options #2 and #3 will definitely require more developer effort. Unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, just use the same repository for everything.

If you go with option #1, you can still view the history separately with minimal effort. For example, you could mark front-end commits with *"FE: foo"* and back-end commits with *"BE: bar"* to identify them. As long as you are consistent about including the right prefixes, you can run:

```
git log --grep='^FE:'
```

to see just the changes to your front-end code.